# Como hacer para que mi page de flutter no se reinicie constantemente?

Tags: firebase, flutter

estoy creando una aplicaciones en flutter y una de sus funciones es una libreta, esta es la page que cree para editar las notas pero al abrir la page me hace la consulta bien pero el problema  tengo  es que constantemente se me esta reiniciando y me empieza a generar un bucle infinito el cual me empieza a escribir sobre los `TextEditingControler` infinitamente y no me deja modificarlos

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VerNotas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerNotasState createState() => _VerNotasState();
}

String descripcion = '';
String titulo = '';
TextEditingController tituloAsignacion;
TextEditingController descripcionAsignacion;

class _VerNotasState extends State<VerNotas> {
  String controlador;

  void reload() {
    setState(() {
      final identificacion = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      controlador = identificacion;
      tituloAsignacion = TextEditingController(text: titulo);
      descripcionAsignacion = TextEditingController(text: descripcion);
      read();
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    reload();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final identificacion = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    reload();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff212529),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff212529),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 10),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 75,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: tituloAsignacion,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontFamily: 'Coustard'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    maxLengthEnforced: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Titulo',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 260,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: descripcionAsignacion,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: 'Coustard'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    maxLines: 11,
                    maxLengthEnforced: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Descripcion',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    color: Color(0xffb48f18),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("notas")
                        .doc(identificacion)
                        .update({
                      'titulo': tituloAsignacion.text,
                      'descripcion': descripcionAsignacion.text,
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/libreta');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void read() async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    try {
      documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notas')
          .doc(controlador)
          .get();
      print('____');
      print(controlador);
      print(documentSnapshot.get('titulo'));
      print(documentSnapshot.get('descripcion'));
      titulo = documentSnapshot.get('titulo');
      descripcion = documentSnapshot.get('descripcion');
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Este es mi código completo

y el tema es que al hacer la consulta esta se empieza a llamar y a ejecutarse hasta que llega a un bucle infito

```
 void read() async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    try {
      documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notas')
          .doc(controlador)
          .get();
      print('____');
      print(controlador);
      print(documentSnapshot.get('titulo'));
      print(documentSnapshot.get('descripcion'));
      titulo = documentSnapshot.get('titulo');
      descripcion = documentSnapshot.get('descripcion');
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Y al momento de asignar los valores de las consultas a los `TextEditingControles` por el bucle infinito que se crea no me deja editarlos

```
void reload() {
    setState(() {
      final identificacion = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      controlador = identificacion;
      tituloAsignacion = TextEditingController(text: titulo);
      descripcionAsignacion = TextEditingController(text: descripcion);
      read();
    });
  }
```

ya e probado de todo y no lo puedo arreglar seria de mucha utilidad su ayuda muchas gracias

Comment: tienes un ` reload();` dentro del `build` , el ` reload();` tiene un setState, el setState hace que se llame a build, y el build hace que se llame a reload, ahí está el bucle infinito.

Comment: Amigo entonces tu sabes como podria yo hacer para que me haga ese setState es que necesito que me haga la consulta y me actualice los TextEditingControlers por que si le quito el setState no se me actualiza (La única forma de hacerlo sin el setState es entrando y saliendo dos veces para que me los actualiza) y sin crear ese bucle infinito, por que al hacerlo con el setState me los actualiza pero el sigue haciendo las consultas en el bucle y no me deja escribir son los TextEditing, lo que escribo me lo empieza a sobre escribir todo el tiempo

Comment: no necesitas crear los texteditingcontroller de nuevo, ni necesitas setState para eso .

Quedaría así 
  tituloAsignacion.text = titulo;
    descripcionAsignacion.text = descripcion;

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo por tu ayuda, nuevamente me has ayudado demasiado

Comment: ahí lo puse como respuesta, si puedes lo marcas como aceptada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un  `reload();` dentro del build , el  `reload();` tiene un `setState`, el `setState` hace que se llame a build, y el build hace que se llame a `reload`, ahí está el bucle infinito.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente quita el setState y realiza la asignación directamente.

```dart
    
      final identificacion = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      controlador = identificacion;
      tituloAsignacion.text = titulo;
      descripcionAsignacion.text = descripcion;
      read();
```